# LibGDX HTML5 issue

Tags: html, libgdx

I'm making games and deploying them to web and I have ran into big problem, that gwt doesn't have antialiasing which is bad thing.

Does anyone know how to make something like antialiasing for gwt? On Android there is numSamples on desktop samples on html only antialising=true which doesn't do anything, games look bad on gwt in any way.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: any browser, i tested with all of them, chrome, ie, opera, firefox its just crap libgdx is broken with gwt